# Configure ESLint to allow a blank lines before blocks

Tags: javascript, eslint

My ESLint config is such that if I change this

```
if (something) {
    doSomething()
} else {
    doSomethingElse()
}
```

to

```
if (something) {
    doSomething()

} else {
    doSomethingElse()
}
```

I get this error:

> Block must not be padded by blank lines  padded-blocks

I would like to change my ESLint config to allow a single blank line before a block (as above). I tried add the following to my `.eslintrc.js`

```
rules: {
  'vue/html-closing-bracket-newline': 'off',
  'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 'off',
  'vue/attributes-order': 'off',
  'vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline': 'off',
  'no-debugger': 'off',
  'padded-blocks': ['error', {
    blocks: 'never',
    classes: 'never',
    switches: 'never',
  }, {
    allowSingleLineBlocks: true,
  }]
}
```

But it didn't work (blank lines still cause the same error). How can I configure ESLint to allow a blank line before a block?

Answer (score 0):

ESLint doesn't have built-in support. The `padded-blocks` rule can only force spaces at the start **and** end but not for only either. You could, however, create your own custom rule based on the logic that governs it in the first place though.